# No Display in Fullscreen VirtualBox Guests -- AwesomeWM Host

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, virtualization, fullscreen, awesome

I'm using AwesomeWM v3.5.6 on my Host, a Xubuntu 15.10.

I have VirtualBox guest additions installed on all my guest VMs, a Windows 7, another Xubuntu 15.10 and a Kali 2.0.

When I try to switch my VMs to fullsreen, the switch happens, but there is no display (I just see the underlying Host AwesomeWM desktop, I completely loose any display of the guest VM). When I press Host+F again, my VM goes back to windowed mode and display is normal. I don't loose keyboard or mouse input in the VM guest while it's in fullscreen
(I can type stuff in a text editor), it's just that there is no display.

All other guest additions work, including shared clipboard, shared folders etc.

If I boot my Host under XFCE, the fullscreen mode works flawlessly for all VMs. There seems to be some kind of issue with AwesomeWM at play here.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated, even if it's a shot in the dark.

Comment: sounds like a bug in awesomewm. I suggest you use kvm + spice

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the issue you are having: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14323

One workaround is to disable the mini toolbar in your VM UI settings.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late, but this was the top search when I searched for a solution to this problem.  The problem is that you aren't making the AwesomeWM client fullscreen.  Using host+f tells the VirtualBox guest to go fullscreen, but not the AwesomeWM client.

Here is the work-around that I found:

1. Start with two clients, you VirtualBox manager and the guest.
2. While focus is on the manager, type win+j followed immediately by win+f.

Doing this quickly allows you to make the AwesomeWM client fullscreen before VirtualBox takes over the keyboard.